# Jquery serialization with input updating

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

I have a problem with jquery and serialize method.

I have a form, that I send via `$.ajax` method. In this method I use `serialize();`.  Before I call serialize I use a function that modifies the 2 input text values, but on serialize the 2 inputs send the old values.

This is my code.

```
$('#formANAGRAFICA3').submit(function() { 
    codeAddress();
    var $form = $('#formANAGRAFICA3'); 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data : $form.serialize(),
        url: $form.attr( 'action' ),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#editANAGRAFICA3').show();
        }
    });
    return false;
});

function codeAddress() { 
    var address = 'my value';
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) { 
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
            var pos = results[0].geometry.location;
            map.setCenter(pos);
            marker.setPosition(pos);
            document.getElementById("aTitle33").value = pos.lat(); 
            document.getElementById("aTitle34").value = pos.lng();
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

When it send the form, the data received is not updated, even though I modified the input text values with the `codeAddress` function. Why?

Comment: Please put your code in a code block, so that it is readable.

Comment: Are you certain that the code within the `codeAddress` function is executed?  You have some conditional expressions that could prevent it from running.  Is your `status` variable **really** equal to `google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`codeAddress()` does *not* modify your input fields instantly. Instead, it issues an AJAX (asynchronous) request, and updates your inputs when the response comes in. In the meantime, the rest of your code proceeds as normal.

As a timeline:

1. Call `codeAddress()`
2. Issue AJAX request to Google maps
3. Return from `codeAddress()`
4. Serialize and submit form
5. Response from Google comes back.
6. Inputs are modified, too late to be used in the form submit.

The solution is to wait for `geocoder.geocode()` to complete before submitting the form.

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    // Modify inputs
    // Submit form
}
```